# How do I add PIL to PyDev in Eclipse, so i could import it and use it in my project?

Tags: python, django, eclipse, python-imaging-library, pydev

I am trying to work with PIL in my project but the pydev can't seem to find it in my project. First of all I can see it when I enter the python shell, I can import it and I see it in the python sys.path. Second, I Added it to the PYTHONPATH in eclipse.

I restarted eclipse, but still, when I try to do "from PIL import Image" I am getting: "unresolved import".

Can any one please help me here, all other packages I used until now worked great the same way.... and i really need to use PIL

Comment: Is this your first attempt at using pydev?  It sounds like your interpreter is not assigned properly.  check window->preferences->pydev->Interpreter - Python, and make sure you have the python installation loaded there for the version you installed PIL into.

Comment: No, sorry, i am working with eclipse and pydev for a long time, i installed many packages before and they all worked great, just this one is cousing me all the headache.....so i guess i am doing some things right, and one thing wrong somewhere, just don't know where as for all the other packages every things is working great

Comment: I would check that PIL is in the python installation that you have set as your interpreter in the project.

Comment: does your file compile when you add the import?

Comment: Well, It's kind of a moo point at this stage, but thanks guys, the thing is, as i said that on the server i have PIL and it is working, so that is not the problem, the problem is only with the pydev in eclipse, is i am getting unresolved errors, never mind, i waisted too much time on this, I don't really care anymore about the unresolved, and working with it.... thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Had the same problem here.
Got it resolved by adding `/usr/share/pyshared` to the Libraries tab in window->preferences->pydev->Interpreter - Python.

There were a lot of `/usr/lib/python*` paths with the compiled libraries (the C stuff with python bindings) where included already, but not `/usr/share`... parts with the source.

Comment: 10x, I actually got it working, the thing is that for some reason in PyDev it show like there is no PIL, but it is working ok, so I just ignored it, i even can import and use every things from PIL, just getting an error like the PIL is not there....but 10x anyway, this is good :-)

Comment: Which Linux distribution was this?

Answer (score 10):

Try to go to `Window -> Preferences -> Pydev-> Interpreter -> Python Interpreter -> Forced Builtins` tab.
Then add a `PIL` entry and apply.
I've had the same `unresolved import` error when tried to import from this particular package (other packages worked fine), and found [this information](http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html#id1) which finally helped me.

Comment: Thanks. Now I don't get the compilation error on PIL but I can't import Image :(