# The PIL library import fails

Tags: python, eclipse, import, python-imaging-library, pydev

Being a complete begginer in python, I decided to install the python interpreter 3.4.4, and also PyDev plugin for eclipse IDE. I am also using windows 10.

I have encountered a problem regarding certain imports, namely : `from PIL import Image, ImageTk`, which is apparently an unresolved import.

I have looked at certain questions which were similar to my situation, but most of them gave a solution like installing packaged from the linux apt-get. Here are some topics I visited :

1. [Uninstalling and reinstalling Pillow and pip,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505958/why-cant-python-import-image-from-pil)
2. [Installing pillow-imaging-tk on Ubuntu,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22788454/importerror-no-module-named-imagingtk/22788542#22788542)
3. [This topic which left me very confused,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209819/unresolved-import-error-with-pydev-while-using-from-import-as)
4. [This one seemed helpful, but is on Unix OS again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171749/how-do-i-add-pil-to-pydev-in-eclipse-so-i-could-import-it-and-use-it-in-my-proj)

So please, could someone explain to me why I am seeing this error, and how could I correct it if I absolutely want to use Eclipse, Pydev, windows 10 and Python 3.

Comment: What happens when you run the script? Does the error just appear in Eclipse, or does it also happen when you run the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, here's what I did:

1. Set the PYTHONPATH [like it is shown in this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7/4855685#4855685), make sure python.exe is accessible via cmd,
2. Via cmd, type `pip install pillow`. Alternatively, you can enter the same command from Windows+R,
3. (Not sure if relevant step) Via eclipse, `Windows->Preferences->PyDev->PythonInterpreter`remove your interpreter to re-add it,
4. Restart eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

For Python import problems in PyDev, the project web site has a page on [interpreter configuration](http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html) that is a good place to start. I recently had a similar problem that I solved by adding a module to the forced builtins tab.

Comment: I tried adding PIL to the Forced builtins, but the problem persists.