# Failed to import PIL

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

New in python and getting few errors while importing image packages.
I need to use Pillow package in python.
Following packages are already installed in machine:
[image]

and

[image]

Following is folder structure of **C:\Python27\Lib**:

[image]

still getting error(PIL Package not found) while using following statement:

```
from PIL import Image
```

Same error with following:

```
import Image
```

already tried:

- [Why can't Python import Image from PIL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505958/why-cant-python-import-image-from-pil)
- [The PIL library import fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36900272/the-pil-library-import-fails)

and rest.

I also observed, when open command line enter python and then place below command, its not giving error. I dont know what does it mean by:
[image]
Thanks for reading !

Comment: Perhaps you have 2 versions of python installed on your PC?

Comment: @user5214530 Correct me anything wrong "python -V" giving only one result "Python 2.7.16"

Comment: That is indeed the problem. Pillow seems to be installed in Python 2.7, but not in Python 3.7.

Comment: @santoshdhanawade Note how the title of the bottom image says "Python 3.7 (32-bit)". Try `pip3 install pillow` or `python3 -m pip install pillow`

Comment: Sorry for delay Santosh. Check out L3viathan comments, I think that can indeed be a problem. Check your environmental paths to determine the truth :)

Comment: Thank you both for such positive response. :). seems to be mixing between both version give me some time will let you know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python2.x and Python3.x use separate `site-packages`.

See also [what is site-packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31384639/what-is-pythons-site-packages-directory)

On Linux...

```
$ python -m site
sys.path = [
    '/home/<username>',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
]
USER_BASE: '/home/<username>/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/home/<username>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True


$ python3 -m site
sys.path = [
    '/home/<username>',
    '/usr/lib/python36.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.6',
    '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
    '/home/<username>/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/home/<username>/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/home/<username>/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages' (exists)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

On Windows, the paths are usually something like...

```
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages'
'C:\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages'
```

If you want to use `PIL` in both versions (2.7.16 and 3.7.4) you need to install the `Pillow` package into each. I.e.

```
pip install Pillow
pip3 install Pillow
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Will let you know result.

Comment: Yes, it is, pip3 worked for my python3 version.